# CREATE DATABASE never ends

Tags: postgresql

I cannot create a database with postgres 9.6.12, viewing pg_activity there's no blocking and waiting queries

this is my query:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+------------------------------------ 
datid            | 16390 
datname          | mydb 
pid              | 7275 
usesysid         | 10 
usename          | postgres96 
application_name | pgAdmin III - Query Tool 
client_addr      | myip 
client_hostname  | mypc
client_port      | 55202 
backend_start    | 2019-07-22 09:12:11.238705-04 
xact_start       | 2019-07-22 09:12:13.010278-04
query_start      | 2019-07-22 09:12:13.010278-04 
state_change     | 2019-07-22 09:12:13.010282-04 
wait_event_type  | 
wait_event       |
state            | active 
backend_xid      | 991367173 
backend_xmin     | 991367173 
query            | CREATE DATABASE mydb2\r     +
                 |   WITH OWNER = postgres96\r        +
                 |        ENCODING = 'UTF8'\r         +
                 |        TABLESPACE = system\r       +
                 |        LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'\r+
                 |        LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'\r  +
                 |        CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

why is tacking so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... after dropping all subscriptions of pglogical and restart de service I could create the database (I couldn't after a simple restart)